# get average of number of likes in mysql from two tables

Tags: mysql

let's say I have a `posts` table:

```
post_id    user_id    text
1             2        abcd
2             1        wert
3             3        yhj
```

and I have a `ranks` table:

```
post_id     liker_user_id      score
1              3                 3
3              4                 1
3              3                 5
```

I want to get `avg(score)` for each post so I came up with this simple query:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.text , avg(ranks.score) as `ranking` FROM posts LEFT JOIN ranks ON ranks.post_id = posts.post_id GROUP BY posts.post_id;
```

so this is fine but the problem is, it is possible that a post does not have any ranking in the `ranks` table, so there will be nothing in the ranking field and it gives me something like this:

```
post_id   text   ranking
1         abcd     3
2         wert     
3         yhj      3
```

note that there is nothing in ranking for `post_id = 2`.
I want a zero for such results, like this:

```
post_id   text   ranking
1         abcd     3
2         wert     0
3         yhj      3
```

how can I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to return zero if it has no results like so:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.text , COALESCE(AVG(ranks.score),0) as `ranking` 
  FROM posts 
  JOIN ranks 
    ON ranks.post_id = posts.post_id 
 GROUP BY posts.post_id;
```